# Stack Overflow loading icon at the tab never stops if I view a question

Tags: bug

I just noticed it recently: Every time I view a question at Stack Overflow the loading icon never stops spinning. Though it doesn't slow down anything, I find it annoying.

Is this a bug? Or is it my browser? I don`t think this is an Internet issue because other sites load just fine.

My browser is Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit), and the
OS is Windows 10 - 64-bit.

Here's a screenshot. It only occurs if I view a question. No problem if I go to my profile.

[image]

Comment: Some more details would help - what browser? What OS? What versions of both? Which exact loading icon do you mean? On what page? Can you provide screenshots that show *exactly* what you mean? It is very difficult to know what you are referring to without these details.

Comment: Edited my question with more details. Hope it helps. Been experiencing that for days now.

Comment: When you open the developer console and refresh, can you see what network items are still waiting to load?

Comment: `wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/` and `ados.js` are pending.

Comment: The websockets is expected, that shouldn't be a problem. The `ados.js` is coming from an ad server, which may be very slow and is causing the issue you are seeing. Unfortunately, that's not under our control - does the URL for it load for you at all?

Comment: aside from the seemingly never ending loading icon, the page works just fine. I'm just curious :)

Comment: Well, the ad hasn't loaded (the big empty space)... so it's not working *completely* fine (from an advertisers point of view at least) ;-)

Comment: You have some adblocker installed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't have one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually noticed this problem a lot on my computer too, and I've noticed that this only happens on my laptop, not on an iPad or on an Android smartphone.

While it doesn't disrupt my interaction with the site, it often causes the site to *lag* as I scroll up or down, but that's just as bad as it gets. I noticed that this happens because of the ad that is loading. Alternatively, you may have an adblocker installed, so that could be causing a slowdown in the page-loading.

So, to answer your question, this has *nothing* to do with your Internet connection, or StackExchange; it simply depends on your computer HDD/SDD speed, extra software interference like adblockers, background tasks runnning that slow overall PC performance and reduce RAM availability for your browser operation, and/or browser speed itself.

What I recommend doing is clicking the "X" button after the page has completely loaded; I've found that it causes no problem to the site if you do that.

Comment: "sometimes, the ads comprise of videos" - we do not allow animations or video in our ads. If you see that, it is either not coming from us (content injected by a third party - ISP or malware, for example), or if it is one of our ad partners, they are not playing by our rules and we need to shut that up.

Comment: I dunno, I sometimes see some ads that are not static, they have some motion graphics that the browser takes long to load

Comment: Again. Not us. We do not allow such ads. If you are seeing them, they are not coming from Stack Exchange. You can confirm that by going over HTTPS - you shouldn't be seeing any such ads anymore (as they can't get injected into our pages by anyone between you and our TLS termination point).

Comment: @Oded Just updated my answer